How to specify "images" outside of the kustomization.yaml file?
I understand that I can do this:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

images:
  - name: myimage
    newTag: newtag

resources:
  - deployment.yaml


But what I thought would be possible would be to do this:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

configurations:
  - images.yaml

resources:
  - deployment.yaml


Where images.yaml is:
images:
  - name: myimage
    newTag: newtag

When I use "images" directly in kustomization.yaml, it works. However, when I reference the images.yaml file using the configuration: feature, it does nothing. According to the Kustomize documentation, that should be possible though:

configurations configurations is used to configure the built-in
Kustomize Transformers to work with CRDs. The built-in Kustomize
configurations can be found here
Examples:
images that should be updated by the images Transformer object

What am I doing wrong?

It should be pointed out I am trying to apply these changes with argocd. Does Argocd not support this? https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/kustomize/


However, when I reference the images.yaml file using the configuration: features

You have misunderstood the purpose of the configurations directive. This is used to provide configuration for the transformers. For example, in the case of the image transformer, you can use a configuration to describe where in a manifest to find image references. This is important when using CRDs. Consider, for example, this hypothetical resource:
apiVersion: mycustomapi/v1
kind: Example
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  image: example

Kustomize has not way of knowing that spec.image is an image reference that should be modified by the image transformer. If we were to use a kustomization.yaml like this:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- example.yaml

images:
  - name: example
    newName: docker.io/traefik/whoami
    newTag: latest

Running kustomize build would simply output the original example.yaml manifest without any changes. We would use the configurations directive and associated configuration file to tell kustomize about this image reference.
If we put the following in images.yaml:
images:
- path: spec/image
  kind: Example

And modify our kustomization.yaml so that it looks like this:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- example.yaml

configurations:
- images.yaml

images:
  - name: example
    newName: docker.io/traefik/whoami
    newTag: latest

Then running kustomize build will produce:
apiVersion: mycustomapi/v1
kind: Example
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest

This is covered more fully here.

It should be pointed out I am trying to apply these changes with argocd. Does Argocd not support this?

ArgoCD is simply calling kustomize. If it's supported by kustomize, it will work with argocd. It's important that you're using the same version of kustomize that argocd is using when you're testing things locally -- this avoids surprises if you're using syntax or features that aren't available in your argocd environment.
